# QField GPS position

Tags: gps, qfield, localisation

I would like to put a .png image on QField and navigate with the GPS over it, on an Android smartphone. I managed to do this in an older version, but now the GPS does not move in the image, anyone know why?

Comment: (Have you enabled position by long click on the gps-icon (crosshair)?)

Comment: Is you png file georeferenced?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if there is an incorrect GPS positioning displayed in QField, which is about 5000 km further south? On some devices this error occurs since the update to QField 2.0.x. The position cursor is then near 0°W/0°N and not where it should be, even if all CRS are correct. I had this error on e.g. an older China cell phone. All the edits I did in my projects were in the correct place, it was only the GPS cursor that was in the wrong position.
The problem disappeared after deinstalling/reinstalling QField.